# Is it ok to have two separate ledger boards

Tags: deck, ledger

I'm replacing the 10' x 8' attached deck on my house with a 16' x 16' attached deck. What I'm wondering is if it would be ok if the ledger board from the old deck could be reused and then another ledger board be installed next to the old one?  The old ledger board would be 10'.

Granted, I realize that if the old board has some damage I should replace it and also check for proper flashing, etc. But I'm just wondering if structurally its ok to use two ledger boards next to each other.

Comment: If it's in good shape and attached properly, no need to replace it. They only make them so long so once a deck extends past that length you have to use more than one anyway. I personally would try to space my joists so one didn't end up on the butt joint. If it did I might do a double there. Not sure if code would specify that or not. I certainly wouldn't toenail a single at a joint, but use a hanger, which would be good to use anyway.

Comment: this should be an answer topshot+

Comment: I will be doing the same. Did you have to do anything special to prevent water dripping in through the seem of where the two ledgers meet? Or did the standard flashing method suffice?